# Inheriting a base class and change the property name

Tags: c#

Consider a Book table structure:

BookId, IsEbook, ISBN, PubDate, EbookFormat

A book can either be a hard copy or an ebook based on IsEbook column value.

The output of a method will have two collection one for Books and other for EBooks.

- Book

  - BookId
  - ISBN
  - PubDate
- EBook

  - EBookId
  - ISBN
  - PubDate
  - EbookFormat

BookId and EBookId are different properties which take their values from BookId column.

Do I create two classes, one for Book and other for Ebook or can I use inheritance in some way because the BookId and EBookId are the same in the table with different name in the output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. A book is book. Whether it's ebook, hardcover, paperback, ... is a _property_ of that book.

Comment: Which iSBN? There are 2 standards ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only common/shared entities should be together in a base class.

If a property has a different name, then it is not shared, so should not be in a common base class, even if it is very, very similar.  So in this case you only have ISBN & PubDate in common.

You can make your base class abstract so that it cannot be instantiated itself.

But you could also use a different approach and specify commonality in an interface, and make your book & EBook classes use this instead of a base class.  Like this:

```
    public interface IBook
    {
        DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
        string ISDN { get; set; }
    }

    public class Book: IBook
    {
        public DateTime PubDate { get ; set ; }   //Comes from IBook
        public string ISDN { get ; set ; }  //Comes from IBook

        public int BookId { get; set; }
    }

    public class EBook : IBook
    {
        public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }   //Comes from IBook
        public string ISDN { get; set; }  //Comes from IBook

        public int EBookId { get; set; }
        public string EbookFormat { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create two classes, Book and EBook, but you could put the BookId, ISBN and PubDate in an interface, e.g. `IBook`. In that way, you can write logic that applies to both, without having the same property names.